# What is the difference between StatelessSession and Session in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session

What is the difference between `StatelessSession` and `Session` in NHibernate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between sessionfactory.openSession() and sessionfactory.openStatelessSession()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496995/difference-between-sessionfactory-opensession-and-sessionfactory-openstatelesss)

Comment: answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679636/nhibernate-isession-vs-istatelesssession)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NHibernate - ISession vs. IStatelessSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679636/nhibernate-isession-vs-istatelesssession)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Stateless session is not tracking entities that are retrieved. For example for regular `ISession` following code:

```
var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession()
using(var transaction = session.BeginTransaction()){
    var user = session.Get<User>(1);
    user.Name = "changed name";
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

will result in update in DB. This tracking consumes memory and makes `ISession` performance to degrade over time since amount of tracked entities is growing.

The same code with `IStatelessSession` won't do anything. Stateless sessions are used when you need to load lots of data and perform some batching operations. It can be used to work with large data sets in a more "ado.net" style.

Comment: This answer needs more detail about `StatelessSession`.  How about a code example where you DO update the database with a `StatelessSession`?

Answer (score 2):

Session in the NHibernate caches all the inserted data in the session level cache.

```
 using (var session = sessionFact.OpenSession())
         {
            using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
              for (int  = 0; i < 500000; i++)
              {
                 Student st = new Student(
                 {  
                      ID = 1,
                      FirstName = "Zia",
                      LastName = "Qammar"
                 });

                 session.Save(st);
               }

               trans.Commit();
            }
          }
```

above code throw an "OutOfMemoryException" exception while inserting 50,000 student in the database. 
The other approach that NHibernate provides is StatelessSession which persist the data in database in detached objects.

```
using (var session = sessionFact.OpenStatelessSession())
             {
                using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                  for (int  = 0; i < 500000; i++)
                  {
                     Student st = new Student(
                     {  
                          ID = 1,
                          FirstName = "Zia",
                          LastName = "Qammar"
                     });

                     session.Save(st);
                   }

                   trans.Commit();
                }
              }
```