# Remove deleted items from first level cache in NHibernate? Or: how to check if cached items have been deleted?

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency, multi-user, first-level-cache

We have a brownfield multi-user application (99% Delphi, 1% .net) which uses NHibernate for the persistency of the .net modules. In my application I can add categories to some entity. If I select one and decide to not use it (thus removing the category again) I has been loaded by NHibernate and will stay in the session's first level cache. Now, if some other user deletes this category and I try to save my entity my application throws an exception because the object loaded doesn't exist anymore.

my question: is there a way to check if my cache has items loaded which don't exist anymore? and if so, is there a way to remove non-exist entities from my cache?

So what happens:
I load an entity (added to session cache)
I add a category (added to session cache)
Someone else deletes the category from the database.
I save my entity and the exception occurs because the category doesn't exist anymore.

It's still in the session cache. It would be nice if I could (automatically) remove it from my session's cache? is there a way to clean up the cache and remove objects that don't exist anymore?

Regards, Ted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no option in NHibernate to do it automatically, at least not with `ISession`. You could use `IStatelessSession` for loading, since it doesn't have first-level cache, but you'll lose many [other features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679636/nhibernate-isession-vs-istatelesssession) that `ISession` provides.

You could also call `ISession.Clear()` to clear the session (first-level) cache, or `ISession.Evict()` to evict certain entities from session, but that's not automatic.

How long do you keep your session object? Maybe you need a different session management [context](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-current-session).

If the lifespan of your session is shorter, you can still achieve entity caching, but with [second-level cache](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-cache). [SysCache2](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2) is one of [second-level cache providers](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#caches) that has a support for [`SqlCacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx). This means that you could set cache expiration when some objects in database change.